Incorrect roof vent for bathroom fan?
We had our house re-reroofed a month ago. I just noticed that they replaced the previous bathroom fan roof vent with this T-style vent with a wide oval base:

That wide base gave me a bad feeling, and sure enough when I looked in the attic, the bathroom fan vent pipe is just pushed into that wide opening with a piece of tape holding it there, partially dangling. That's not the right vent at all, is it? Because I don't see how you could possibly make that connection airtight so that all the moist air goes outside and not back into the attic.
Shouldn't it be more like this, so that you can clamp the vent pipe to it? (The vent pipe for the bathroom fan is an insulated 4" flexible hose.)

What is the correct use of those T-pipes? Just for general attic air venting?
And what is the fix for this? The cheap way I suppose would be to apply more tape so it's somewhat airtight underneath that thing, bit I suspect the right way is to replace that T-vent with a clampable one.
Here's a pic of the underside. I removed the piece of tape already but it was just pushed up into that opening to direct its airflow into the screen above. It might be hard to tell the dimensions, but the hose is 4", and the opening above is about 6"x6".


And it looks like that vent is intended for a different application, like a kitchen vent.

@SteveSh The screen is to keep critters out. On a dryer exhaust those screens often clog with lint, which is far less likely on a pure vent exhaust. Not having the screen does risk bird, squirrel or other rodent setting up housekeeping inside the vent, or using it as the access to rip open crummy flex duct and enter your attic if crummy flext duct was used for the duct.

@Ecnerwal, I added a pic of the underside showing how the hose was just pushed into it and held with a piece of foil tape.

You're right that this isn't ideal. It's also not really a concern in terms of moisture. As compared to a dryer vent, a bath vent emits a fairly tiny amount of humidity.
Anyway, my fix would be to get a 6" to 4" duct reducer, clamp your hose to it, and mount the big end up in that vent stack with hanger strap screwed to the rafters. It doesn't need to be air-tight. It just needs to be close.
